# Correct way of performing lamp aarti

Tags: rituals, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava, gaudiya-vaishnavism, iskcon

I've heard the following ways of performing Lamp aarti:

offer four circles to the lotus feet, two circles to the navel, and three circles to the Lord’s face; then offer seven circles to the Lord’s whole body.(ISKCON)

Others say only one circle to lord's face and rest is same.

I'm looking for a shastric evidence.

I've found a video of ramanandi guru Jagadguru Rambhracharya Ji Maharaj but couldn't find the shloka he recited. https://youtu.be/Gj6ufc8N6mU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ve found this shloka in “Aarti Sangrah from Gita Press” but couldn’t find the source of the shloka.

[image]

As per the shloka:
four circles to the lotus feet, two circles to the navel, and **One** circle to the Lord’s face and then seven circles to the Lord’s whole body.